# Code does not pass first validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a function in which I am first checking that a string passed as argument has letters only or not. But it always return as false. Below is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XLDGf/)

```
function takeString (str) {
    var regex = "/^[A-Za-z]+$/";

    if (str.match(regex)) {
        if (str.charCodeAt(0) === str.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0)) {
            alert('true');
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            alert('false');
            return false;
        }
    } 
    else {
        alert('Only letters please.');
    }
}

takeString('string');
```

​
The above code always alerts `Only letters please`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to get rid of the quotes to make `regex` a regular expression literal:

```
var regex = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XLDGf/2/).

Currently, `regex` refers to a string literal. When you pass something that's not a regular expression object or literal to `String#match`, it implicitly converts that argument to a regular expression object (see [ES5 15.5.4.10](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.10)):

> - If Type(*regexp*) is Object and the value of the [[Class]] internal property of *regexp* is `"RegExp"`, then let *rx* be *regexp*;
> - Else, let *rx* be a new RegExp object created as if by the expression `new RegExp(` *regexp*`)` where `RegExp` is the standard built-in constructor with that name.

Your regular expression is therefore interpreted like this (since the string contains the forward slash characters you were expecting to delimit a regular expression literal):

```
var regex = /\/^[A-Za-z]+$\//;
```

That can't match anything, since it's looking for a forward slash, followed by the start of the string.

Comment: Was about to post the same :) You can make the regex even shorter: `/^[a-z]+$/g`

Comment: Could you please help me why my jsfiddle return false when I give string like this `This is a string`? How can I change it so that it also accepts such strings? Thank you

Comment: @x4f4r - That doesn't work because there are spaces in the string, and your regular expression only matches letters. Just add a space to the regex and it will work with that string.

Comment: I added space this way `/^\s[a-z]+$/` but does not work. I also tried this `/\s[a-z]+$/` works for `This is string` but does not work for `String`.

Comment: @x4f4r - Read up on regular expressions. Try adding the space inside the square brackets.